# How to append one dataframe into another dataframe as a column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

May be my issue description is wrong but what is described below. I need solution in pyspark.

I have 2 data frames

```
Df1
A B C
1 2 3
5 6 7
8 9 1
6 2 3

Df2
D E
a b
c d
e f
```

I want final dataframe as below

```
A B C D E
1 2 3 a b
1 2 3 c d
1 2 3 e f
5 6 7 a b
5 6 7 c d
5 6 7 e f
8 9 1 a b
8 9 1 c d
8 9 1 e f
6 2 3 a b
6 2 3 c d
6 2 3 e f
```

Basically new dataframe will be for each row for DF1 will repeat for each row of DF2.
Final count would be : `count(Df1) * count(Df2)`

Please help, I am new to pysaprk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crossJoin`, which is `df.crossJoin(df2)`. You can check this https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html.